Using SVG in flutter creates lag
I am using SVG in flutter and while using svg. Where svg is rendered there i am getting some janks and app gets lag.
I am currently using Svgpicture.asset and also caching the svg pre using them.
 for (String element in cacheSvgImages) {
      var loader = SvgAssetLoader(element);
      svg.cache
          .putIfAbsent(loader.cacheKey(null), () => loader.loadBytes(null));
    }


Could you give an example of your image in SVG format?

Use the cacheImage method to load image in memories before the image render in view.
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String svgAsset = 'assets/my_svg.svg';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precachePicture(
      ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderBuilder, svgAsset),
      context,
    );
    
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('SVG Optimization')),
        body: Center(
          child: SvgPicture.asset(svgAsset),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

///flutter built-in cache image provider
Future cacheImage(BuildContext context, String imageUrl) => precacheImage(
      CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageUrl),
      context,
    );


Avoid code-only answers. Please at least provide some explanations.

You could have noticed that precachePicture has been deprecated. any other solution.

I want svg to be cached before

Future cacheImage(BuildContext context, String imageUrl) => precacheImage(
CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageUrl),
context,
);

try this one method only change image provider in this and call it in your init state.
